# Hot to trigger a click event with a dataset that has values as an array

Tags: jquery

I have a couple of elements on my site which has a dataset element. Instead of creating a couple of new dataset elements I wanted to use 1 dataset element which can have multiple values depending on the settings. How can I trigger with jquery like the example below?

```js
$('[data-trigger=click]').on('click', function(e) {
  alert('yes it works');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-trigger='["click", "impression", "someother"]'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `*=` so the selector will check if the `data-*` contains `your_string` :

```
$('[data-trigger*="click"]').on('click' , function(e){
    alert('yes it works');
});
```

```js
$('[data-trigger*="click"]').on('click', function(e) {
  alert('yes it works');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-trigger='["click", "impression", "someother"]'>DIV CONTENT</div>
```